# Is it possible to both save Josie Thorpe and capture Zeke Sanders?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

In my second, more violent playthrough of Deus Ex: Human Revolution, I'm trying to both save Josie Thorpe (in order to get the weapons dealer discount from her husband) and capture Zeke Sanders (because I'm a dog of the Serif corporation). Unfortunately, when I choose to fight Zeke, I'm frozen to the ground while he shoots a bullet through Josie Thorpe's head, so my signature Jenson Mercy FacePunch lands just too late.

Is there any way to resolve this confrontation in a way such that I save Josie Thorpe and capture Zeke Sanders?

Comment: I'm glad you only want to save the hostage because you can save money on guns that way.

Comment: Woah man, I'm not aiming for murder here.

Comment: Touché, my friend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try shooting him in the leg then going for a takedown.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even realize you could shoot your gun during the execution animation. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative, if you originally ask Sarif for a stungun (non-lethal; short range), you should have no problems taking him out with it. You can fire much faster than Zeke. It's not like there's a shortage of lethal firearms (10mm Pistols, mostly) in the plant.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can. Here's an example shot to the log and double take down.

Caution... you will probably LOL extremely hard when watching.

Comment: [Hold my beer...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3VLMQBgjdQ)

Answer (score 1):

Stun gun works (just did it), you can then pop him in the head without being attacked by SWAT. That way he can't be questioned, though.

Comment: Hey alaroo, welcome to the site. I'm confused; are you asking a question here? This seems like it was intended to be a comment on Raven Dreamer's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also tranq him before he shoot's her, that is what I did. Worked just fine... thought I missed on my first try, and zooming in took too long. Just go for a body shot. :)